# store enable_shared_from_this based class pointer(this) within itelf

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers

What if I create new class based on `std::enable_shared_from_this`. And store it's `shared_from_this()` method result as a member `std::shared_ptr`:

```
class B : public std::enable_shared_from_this<B> {
    public: 
        B(){
           sharedThisPtr_ = shared_from_this();
        }

    private:
        std::shared_ptr<B> sharedThisPtr_;

    };
```

Will such class object will be ever destructed and deallocated?

```
int main(void){
    auto myObj = std::make_shared<B>();
}
```

Comment: terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_weak_ptr'
  what():  bad_weak_ptr

Comment: The above was for GCC 4.7.2, and for visual studio 2013 `Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_weak_ptr at memory location 0x00C9F164.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This won't work, even after fixing the syntax error: `shared_from_this` requires that there be at least one `shared_ptr` instance that owns `*this`. During initialisation, no `shared_ptr` owns it.

You might get an exception, an empty shared pointer, or some other kind of undefined behaviour.

If you were to set `sharedThisPtr` later, once `myObj` owns it, then it would act like any other shared pointer, preventing destruction as long as it shares ownership of the object. So, in that case, the object will never be destroyed unless you reset `sharedThisPtr`.